# Getting a specific item from a list (drools)

Tags: java, drools

I want to access a particular index of a list from drools file.

eg : My POJO(fact) is :

```
package com.test.demo;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    private List<String> addresses;
    private long id;

    //Getters and Setters here
}
```

My DRL rule is :

```
rule "ValidateTestBooleanCheck"
    /* Iterating over a list */
    when Test($addresses : addresses)
         String() from $addresses
    then
        System.out.println("Tested");
end
```

I get that in this my rule is testing for all valid string addresses. My requirement though is that I want to directly go to the second and fourth element of the list of addresses and apply some rule on that particular item in the list.

Comment: well it's list so just use addresses.get(1); for second element

Comment: You can use a custom field for this case.

Comment: @SławomirCzaja, how about the fourth element too?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera did not quite get you

Comment: You can define `private List<String> addressesToCheck;` with 2nd and 4th elements from `addresses` and use this new field in the rule instead of  `addresses`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (although I would recommend you to change your model if you can to better reflect the differences between addresses):

```
rule "Sample"
when
    Test($addresses : addresses)
    $a1: String() from $addresses.get(1)
    $a2: String() from $addresses.get(3)
then
    System.out.println("Second Address: "+$a1);
    System.out.println("Fourth Address: "+$a2);
end
```

This is assuming all your `Test` objects have at least 4 addresses.

Hope it helps,